# Retrieve instance from factory based on parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to retrieve an instance of a class based on the parameterized type of its' superclass. The way I'm currently doing seems like it should work, but for some reason I get a compilation issue.

```
class Fruit {}

class Apple extends Fruit {}

public interface FruitHandler<T> {
    void handle(T handle);
}

public class AppleHandler implements FruitHandler<Apple> {
    @Override public void handle(Apple apple) {
        System.out.println("Handling apple...");
    }
}
```

The following is the factory class with the issue:

```
public class FruitHandlerFactory {

    public <T> FruitHandler<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz == Apple.class) {
            // This line is causing the error
            return new AppleHandler();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I receive the following compilation error:

```
Error:(7, 14) java: incompatible types
  required: FruitHandler<T>
  found:    AppleHandler
```

In this case, `T` is `Apple`, so shouldn't `AppleHandler` be an instance of `FruitHandler<T>`?

Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: @Xipo has it right, but perhaps you want to know the reason.  Effectively, `AppleHandler` gets the Java type `? extends FruitHandler<T>`. This type is strictly bigger than `FruitHandler<T>` and not assignment compatible with it. So you need to downcast to the smaller type.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `cast` the result to `FruitHandler<T>`. This should do it:

`return (FruitHandler<T>) new AppleHandler();`

The problem lies to the fact that the compiler **cannot** know at that point, what `<T>` will be; so its expecting to return a `<T>` type while you are actually returning an `Apple`.

To answer your comment, there is a way to avoid the *explicit* casting to the return type

```
        if (clazz == Apple.class) {
            FruitHandler fh =  new AppleHandler();
            return  fh;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Xipo. This results in an unchecked cast though. Generally, I've thought that if you have to use an unchecked cast there is likely better design. Is there something I could do differently (in terms of design) to avoid the unchecked cast?